# Creating coffee class. Important function is __init__ and method simulates coffee brewing

Tags: python, computer-science

This method simulates the action of brewing coffe. This process can only take place if the machine has water, a filter, coffe grounds, the coffe pot is empty, and the machine is currently off.
The result of this process is that was tank becomes empty, and the coffe pot is set to same amount that present in water tank, machine remains on, coffe pot is not clean.

```
class Coffee:
    def __init__(self):
        self.refill= 20
        self.watertank=20
        self.filter= False
        self.on=False
        self.spoons=4
        self.machine=False
        self.pot= 0
def brew(self): # And as requirment
        if (machine == self.watertank and machine == self.filter \
        and machine == self.spoons and machine == self.pot \
        and machine == self.on):
            print("The coffee is brewing")
            while self.on == True:
                if self.watertank < 20:
                    if self.pot==self.watertank:
                        return False
```

the functions must work. My explanation of what I'm trying to do is I created variable in constructor machine to be define as true. If machine is True, filter True, spoons ==4, pot ==0, and self.on is False. which the result will be

water tank ==0, pot== water tank, self.on == True, pot ==0

Can you guys take look at my function? What kind of changes I can do? I added all command instead of And. Can you guys us check out the constructor to understand this method more.

Comment: What error or problem are you receiving?  You haven't stated what your issue is with the code above, which is probably why someone downvoted your post

Comment: To expand on that a bit -- we ask that any question that include code have the *shortest possible code* that allows others to produce a *specific error* (which should be itself included in the question). See the [mcve] definition -- so you should (1) show a specific error, and (2) provide the shortest code you tested to produce that same error when run on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Well a couple of things jump out.

1. You are not increasing the level of `self.pot` or decreasing the level of `self.watertank` anywhere.
2. The coffee maker never gets turned on, therefore your brewing `if` statement will never be executed.
3. The brewing `if` statement compares things that don't make sense.  Why are you comparing `machine` with `self.watertank` for example? Those two properties don't relate as one is an integer and the other is a bool.
4. There are several properties that could/should be contained in separate classes of each object, like a separate class for `Pot` and another for `Watertank` that holds properties like `original_level` and has methods for `is_empty`, etc.
5. Adding helper methods to your class to load the spoons, install the filter, turn on/off the machine, etc. are helpful additions as well so your class can be easily interacted with.
6. I created a `Container` abstract class that is never intended to be used directly, but instead, only ever should be extended by another class.  This abstract class will hold the base functionality for each of the classes that implement it.

```
import abc

class Container (object):
    __meta__ = abc.ABCMeta

    level           = None
    original_level  = None

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def increase (self, amt=1):
        self.level = self.level + amt

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def decrease (self, amt=1):
        self.level = self.level - amt

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.level == 0


class Pot (Container):
    def __init__(self, level):
        self.level          = level
        self.original_level = level

class Watertank (Container):
    def __init__(self, level):
        self.level          = level
        self.original_level = level

class Coffee:
    def __init__(self):
        self.refill     = 20
        self.watertank  = Watertank(20)
        self.pot        = Pot(0)    
        self.filter     = False
        self.on         = False
        self.spoons     = 0

    def brew(self): # And as requirment
        if self.is_ready():
            print("The coffee is brewing...")

            while self.on :             
                self.watertank.decrease( 1 )
                self.pot.increase( 1 )

                if self.pot.level == self.watertank.original_level and self.watertank.is_empty() :
                    print("The coffee has been brewed. Enjoy!")
                    break
        else :
            print("Sorry, the brewer is not ready to brew.")
            self.ready_check()

    def ready_check(self):
        if self.watertank.level == 0 :
            print( "The Watertank is not filled." )
        if not self.filter :
            print( "A filter has not been loaded." )
        if self.spoons == 0 :
            print( "There are no spoons of coffee mix." )
        if self.pot.level > 0 :
            print( "The Pot is not empty." )
        if not self.on:
            print( "The brewer is not turned on." )

    def is_ready(self):
        return  self.watertank.level > 0 \
            and self.filter \
            and self.spoons > 0\
            and self.pot.level == 0 \
            and self.on

    def add_spoons(self, amt=1):
        self.spoons = self.spoons + amt

    def install_filter(self):
        self.filter = True
        print("A filter has been installed.")

    def turn_on (self):
        self.on = True
        print("The brewer is now on!")

    def turn_off (self):
        self.on = False
        print("The brewer is now off!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    brewer = Coffee()
    brewer.install_filter()
    brewer.add_spoons(4)
    brewer.turn_on()

    brewer.brew()
```

Also, I was super bored and continued to explore this use-case.  I added a barista who can personalize your coffee order by asking a few questions about preference.  Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/sadmicrowave/73541a76f8133be09c8318c0770c5343

Comment: This was a lot of effort for a question that didn't clearly specify a specific problem; while you've clearly done the OP a service, it's worth noting that [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) explicitly advises *against* answering such questions until they're clarified (note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions").

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I was bored and like building classes; so I thought I'd give it a shot